# Get user timezone label value in formula field salesforce

Tags: formula-field

I have created a formula field **User Timezone** and I want the current login user timezone value.

I have written the formula

User Timezone = TEXT($User.TimeZoneSidKey)

but I am getting the value **Asia/Kolkata** but I want **(GMT+05:30) India Standard Time (Asia/Kolkata)**
this value in my formula field. Please help me to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such formula function to get the picklist label yet.
You can do some workaround by apex code.

Create a new text field TimeZone_Txt__c to store the timezone label text.
Write some code in trigger to set the label to the text field before any user is created or user timezone is changed. Some code for your reference:

```
if(Trigger.isBefore && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)) {
    Map<String, String> val_labelMap = new Map<String, String>();
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry et : User.TimeZoneSidKey.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()) {
        val_labelMap.put(et.getValue(), et.getLabel());
    }

    for(User u : Trigger.new) {
        if(Trigger.oldMap != null && u.TimeZoneSidKey == Trigger.oldMap.get(u.Id).TimeZoneSidKey) {
            continue;
        }
        u.TimeZone_Txt__c = val_labelMap.get(u.TimeZoneSidKey);
    }
}
```

Export all the existing user with Id and timezone info(label) by report. Update back to TimeZone_Txt__c field.

Use $User.TimeZone_Txt__c instead.

More reference: [PicklistEntry Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_PicklistEntry.htm#apex_class_Schema_PicklistEntry)